# How to exports strings from a WPF application code for internationalization?

Tags: c#, wpf, localization, internationalization

I'm trying to modify an existing C# application for internationalization. The process for WPF has some [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/how-to-localize-an-application) and seems reasonably transparent as I can continue to develop normally and run `msbuild` from time to time and check if everything holds. However, while going through the sample project, I realized that it won't cover strings defined in code. In my case, most of them are used for logging and could more or less be easily exported with regexes. This seems a bit hazardous as well as I'm not certain the center will hold if I try to extract C# source with regex. I guess that I could wrap every string in a translation function that will perform the lookup in resources.

I'm not sure how to proceed from there. I'll have a bunch of strings that I could dump in a resx file and another set of strings extracted from the baml files internationalized in another way. Since I'm expecting each method to bring their own complications, I'd rather deal with only half of those complications if possible.

Is there any way to have either method work for both cases? I'd honestly prefer the second one since it makes more sense to me but I guess I could roll with generating a gazillion of Uids and only using 5% - 10% of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I develop multi-language check-in kiosks for one of the worlds busiest international airports (either #1 or #3, depending on how you define it), and in my experience the best solution for this in WPF apps is [custom markup extensions](https://www.wpftutorial.net/LocalizeMarkupExtension.html). First, you can use regular language as your key, which means all of your XAML can be written in whatever language is most convenient for your developers. Secondly, you can [add custom namespaces to the XAML namespaces](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/111911/A-Guide-to-Cleaner-XAML-with-Custom-Namespaces-and), which helps keep your XAML tidy. Third, it's very easy to write utilities to extract your XAML extensions and collate them into Excel spreadsheets (say) for your translators, then incorporate the translations themselves back into your application. Finally, the translation tables themselves can be easily switched at runtime, allowing you to change your language on-the-fly.

Put all this together and all your XAML looks like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Translate 'Text to be translated appears here'}" />
```

And of course it's easy to control which text goes through your translation engine and which text doesn't, by simply controlling exactly where you use your `Translate` markup extension.

Comment: Thank you for this. I'll go with something along those lines. I just don't fully get how it works. Somehow the compiler figures out that having "de" in the resx filename indicates a CultureInfo and magically generates a corresponding folder, then at runtime, the ResourceManager checks the CurrentUICulture and magically figures that the non-default language "de" has a folder and loads the resource dll?